# Rails 5 - how to write a scope

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, scope

I am trying to learn how to write scopes in Rails 5.

I have a user model and a proposal model. The associations are:

User:

```
has_many :proposals
```

Proposal:

```
belongs_to :user
```

In my proposal model, Im trying to figure out how to write a scope that finds the proposals that belong to the user that created them.

I am trying:

```
scope :proponent,   -> { where(user_id: user.id) }
```

I have tried a million variations on this but I can't find one that works.

This particular attempt gives this error:

```
2.3.1p112 :001 > Proposal.proponent
NameError: undefined local variable or method `user' for Proposal (call 'Proposal.connection' to establish a connection):Class
```

I have also tried:

```
scope :proponent, -> { where('proposal.user_id = ?', user.id) }
```

The error I get from this attempt is:

```
undefined local variable or method `user' for #<Class:0x007fd3600eb038>
```

I don't know if the error message means the first or second time that I wrote 'user' in my attempt is incorrect. I don't know what "call 'Proposal.connection' means".

Can anyone see what I need to be able to do in order to check the proposals table to find the ones that belong to a specific user?

Comment: Why don't you just take advantage of the associations you already have and do `user.proposals`?

Comment: Because I'm trying to use Pundit - which takes scopes.

Comment: Is it [this Pundit](https://github.com/elabs/pundit)? if so, I'm not sure if the scopes mentioned are rails scopes. From the README it says: "The second argument is a scope of some kind on which to perform some kind of query. It will usually be an ActiveRecord class or a ActiveRecord::Relation, but it could be something else entirely." So using user.proposals should be fine.

Comment: Hi @TamerShlash - the Pundit docs are wrong. I've just been through a long session on codementor which basically just identified all the errors in the pundit readme. I've been struggling for years to learn how to use pundit. Not getting very far. But the advice currently, is that I need a scope. So - figuring that out is my current challenge.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You'll need to pass `user` or `user_id` in as an argument when you call the scope. You can define it like this:

```
scope :proponent,   ->(user){ where(user_id: user.id) }
```

or

```
def self.proponent(user)
  where user_id: user.id
end
```

These really are the same thing.

Then calling it:

```
Proposal.proponent(user)
# => returns a list of proposals for the specific user
```

Note this is the same thing as saying

```
proposal = Proposal.find_by(...)
proposal.user.proposals
```

Comment: When it try the scope the way you suggest, I get an error that says: wrong number of arguments (given 0, expected 1)

Comment: And I get the same error when I try to change the scope the way you wrote it to put "user_id" inside the first set of ()

Comment: @Mel The first error means that you're saying `Proposal.proponent` instead of `Proposal.proponent(user)`.